# Read from a file in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an issue reading my .txt file in Xamarin and I have not find any solution that helps me, I also looked in Stack Overflow's suggestions before I published this.

My app is only Android and I want to randomize a line from the file, I have first made it in C# with console and looks like this =>

```
String[] Card = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Cards.txt");
//string[] Card = { "one", "two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" }; this is what is in the file.
```

However now when I try to do this in Xamarin the filepath is on my computer and not in my phone.
I read at one site to make it an Asset as picture below shows. (I have also tried build action as AndroidAsset)

[image]

I am not sure now if my code is wrong or if it is possible to read from a file. Underneath are 2 examples that I have tried but there are a few more that I have tried but that code is deleted now.

```
String[] text = File.ReadAllLines(Assets.Open("Cards.txt"));


    var currentPath = System.Environment.DataDirectory;
    var Filename = Path.Combine(currentPath, "Cards.txt");
    String[] text = File.ReadAllLines(Filename);
```

I have tried this now but it will not work as an array.

```
        string[] content;
        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Cards.txt")))
        {
            content[] = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        
        txtNumber.Text = content[3];
```

I want the result to be line 3 in the Cards.txt file which will be three.

Comment: Have you went over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows ?

Comment: @Bogmadur According to your screenshot, your project is the only Android, so please set Cards.txt file Build action as **AndroidAsset**, then take a look this article to read file from Asset:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that code lives inside of your Xamarin.Android folder, and it is not in the PCL library, you could try something like this:

```
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: Hi I have no idea what you mean by PCL. I do not understand how this will be an Array? because the hole file is printed in the textView. it works by reading the file but i want to achive more like this but doesn´t work.

Comment: string[] content];
            AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Cards.txt")))
            {
                content[] = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            
            txtNumber.Text = content[3];

Comment: @Bogmadur PCL means portable class library, so in your Xamarin you have a .iOS, .Android and a regular folder where you put in your cross platform UI in. If it was in the PCL you would have two options either use the Xamarin.Essentials nuget which is supposed to act as a single API to give you access to system specific actions like reading from store, or you would need to make an interface, implement it in both projects, and then call it using dependency injection in the PCL

Answer (score 0):

i successfully solved it like this:

```
string content;
        string[] cards = new string[] { "" }; //created a empty string array
        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Cards.txt")))
        {  
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();

        }

        cards = content.Split('\n'); //Split the content after a new row.

        txtNumber.Text = cards[0]; //I changed the number inside cards[3] and it was showing correct value in the txt document.
```